# How to make Kubernetes Network Bridging work like a Hypervisor

Tags: networking, kubernetes

I'm trying to get this working for three days now and I just cant come up with a proper solution. I have an existing environment with virtual machines and I want to do a very simple thing:

- Create a Container (Pod)
- Put it on a specific VLAN Interface on a Bridge that is present and identical on every Kubernetes Node

Thats it! Just as you would do it with any VM on any Hypervisor. You create the VM, say what VLAN it should be in and then start it.

For some reason this feels like the holy grail with Kubernetes and I dont understand why. Everytime there is a Pod IP needed, the IP has to be set on the Worker Node and forwarded to the pod or they want to sell me an internal NAT with Load Balancing etc. This cant be it.

I have tried the following without success:

- Using calico in a number of configurations
- Using flanell in a number of configurations
- Created stuff like "CustomResourceDefinitions" and "NetworkAttachmentDefinitions" with a wide variety of configuration examples and tests.
- Tried manually scripting a lot on the node prior to configuring a pod

Custom Resource Definition:

```
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: network-attachment-definitions.k8s.cni.cncf.io
spec:
  group: k8s.cni.cncf.io
  versions:
  - name: v1
    served: true
    storage: true
    schema:
      openAPIV3Schema:
        type: object
        properties:
          spec:
            x-kubernetes-preserve-unknown-fields: true
  scope: Namespaced
  names:
        plural: network-attachment-definitions
        singular: network-attachment-definition
        kind: NetworkAttachmentDefinition
        shortNames:
        - net-attach-def
```

Network Attachment Definition with tests:

```
apiVersion: "k8s.cni.cncf.io/v1"
kind: NetworkAttachmentDefinition
metadata:
  name: macvlan-conf
spec:
  config: '{
    "name": "mynet",
    "type": "flannel",
    "delegate": {
      "bridge": "mynet0",
      "mtu": 1400
    }
  }

#    "cniVersion": "0.3.1",
#    "name": "mynet",
#    "type": "bridge",
#    "bridge": "mynet0",
#    "vlan": 100,
#    "ipam": {}
#  }'

#  config: '{
#    "cniVersion": "0.3.1",
#    "type": "vlan",
#    "master": "enp0s3",
#    "mtu": 1500,
#    "vlanId": 5,
#    "linkInContainer": false,
#    "ipam": {
#      "type": "host-local",
#      "subnet": "172.31.0.0/24"
#    },
#    "dns": {
#      "nameservers": [ "10.1.1.1", "8.8.8.8" ]
#    }
#  }'
```

SamplePod:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: samplepod
  annotations:
    k8s.v1.cni.cncf.io/networks: macvlan-conf
spec:
  containers:
  - name: samplepod
    command: ["/bin/ash", "-c", "trap : TERM INT; sleep infinity & wait"]
    image: alpine
```

I'm feeling like I'm missing something very simple here. I verified that vlan and bridging is possible on my nodes. I do not have any errors either in Logs on the nodes or in journalctl. It appears that it just ignores the macvlan-conf.

Does anyone have this environment or knows what I need for that?

Thanks!

Edit: Logs from Creating the Pod

```
Oct 06 08:31:53 debian kubelet[793]: I1006 08:31:53.995353     793 reconciler_common.go:258] "operationExecutor.VerifyControllerAttachedVolume started for volume \"kube-api-access-5hbf8\" (UniqueName: \"kubernetes.io/projected/d7c2b05a-a1a6-424d-b626-0d7f5b1ffebc-kube-api-access-5hbf8\") pod \"samplepod2\" (UID: \"d7c2b05a-a1a6-424d-b626-0d7f5b1ffebc\") " pod="default/samplepod2"
Oct 06 08:31:54 debian containerd[721]: time="2023-10-06T08:31:54.165145664+02:00" level=info msg="RunPodSandbox for &PodSandboxMetadata{Name:samplepod2,Uid:d7c2b05a-a1a6-424d-b626-0d7f5b1ffebc,Namespace:default,Attempt:0,}"
Oct 06 08:31:54 debian kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Oct 06 08:31:54 debian kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): cali68b9b56a958: link becomes ready
Oct 06 08:31:54 debian containerd[721]: 2023-10-06 08:31:54.244 [INFO][358123] plugin.go 327: Calico CNI found existing endpoint: &{{WorkloadEndpoint projectcalico.org/v3} {debian-k8s-samplepod2-eth0  default  d7c2b05a-a1a6-424d-b626-0d7f5b1ffebc 245039 0 2023-10-06 08:31:53 +0200 CEST <nil> <nil> map[projectcalico.org/namespace:default projectcalico.org/orchestrator:k8s projectcalico.org/serviceaccount:default] map[] [] [] []} {k8s  debian  samplepod2 eth0 default [] []   [kns.default>
Oct 06 08:31:54 debian containerd[721]: 2023-10-06 08:31:54.244 [INFO][358123] k8s.go 74: Extracted identifiers for CmdAddK8s ContainerID="7f1e4e55ae12bd9d257a47ecb7630ea59029f5da8ef89b3937dec19cbf11d681" Namespace="default" Pod="samplepod2" WorkloadEndpoint="debian-k8s-samplepod2-eth0"
Oct 06 08:31:54 debian containerd[721]: 2023-10-06 08:31:54.275 [INFO][358141] ipam_plugin.go 228: Calico CNI IPAM request count IPv4=1 IPv6=0 ContainerID="7f1e4e55ae12bd9d257a47ecb7630ea59029f5da8ef89b3937dec19cbf11d681" HandleID="k8s-pod-network.7f1e4e55ae12bd9d257a47ecb7630ea59029f5da8ef89b3937dec19cbf11d681" Workload="debian-k8s-samplepod2-eth0"
Oct 06 08:31:54 debian containerd[721]: 2023-10-06 08:31:54.287 [INFO][358141] ipam_plugin.go 268: Auto assigning IP ContainerID="7f1e4e55ae12bd9d257a47ecb7630ea59029f5da8ef89b3937dec19cbf11d681" HandleID="k8s-pod-network.7f1e4e55ae12bd9d257a47ecb7630ea59029f5da8ef89b3937dec19cbf11d681" Workload="debian-k8s-samplepod2-eth0" assignArgs=ipam.AutoAssignArgs{Num4:1, Num6:0, HandleID:(*string)(0xc000298240), Attrs:map[string]string{"namespace":"default", "node":"debian", "pod":"samplepod2",>
Oct 06 08:31:54 debian containerd[721]: 2023-10-06 08:31:54.287 [INFO][358141] ipam_plugin.go 356: About to acquire host-wide IPAM lock.
Oct 06 08:31:54 debian containerd[721]: 2023-10-06 08:31:54.287 [INFO][358141] ipam_plugin.go 371: Acquired host-wide IPAM lock.
Oct 06 08:31:54 debian containerd[721]: 2023-10-06 08:31:54.288 [INFO][358141] ipam.go 107: Auto-assign 1 ipv4, 0 ipv6 addrs for host 'debian'
Oct 06 08:31:54 debian containerd[721]: 2023-10-06 08:31:54.290 [INFO][358141] ipam.go 660: Looking up existing affinities for host handle="k8s-pod-network.7f1e4e55ae12bd9d257a47ecb7630ea59029f5da8ef89b3937dec19cbf11d681" host="debian"
Oct 06 08:31:54 debian containerd[721]: 2023-10-06 08:31:54.294 [INFO][358141] ipam.go 372: Looking up existing affinities for host host="debian"
Oct 06 08:31:54 debian containerd[721]: 2023-10-06 08:31:54.299 [INFO][358141] ipam.go 489: Trying affinity for 192.168.245.192/26 host="debian"
Oct 06 08:31:54 debian containerd[721]: 2023-10-06 08:31:54.301 [INFO][358141] ipam.go 155: Attempting to load block cidr=192.168.245.192/26 host="debian"
Oct 06 08:31:54 debian containerd[721]: 2023-10-06 08:31:54.303 [INFO][358141] ipam.go 232: Affinity is confirmed and block has been loaded cidr=192.168.245.192/26 host="debian"
Oct 06 08:31:54 debian containerd[721]: 2023-10-06 08:31:54.303 [INFO][358141] ipam.go 1180: Attempting to assign 1 addresses from block block=192.168.245.192/26 handle="k8s-pod-network.7f1e4e55ae12bd9d257a47ecb7630ea59029f5da8ef89b3937dec19cbf11d681" host="debian"
Oct 06 08:31:54 debian containerd[721]: 2023-10-06 08:31:54.305 [INFO][358141] ipam.go 1682: Creating new handle: k8s-pod-network.7f1e4e55ae12bd9d257a47ecb7630ea59029f5da8ef89b3937dec19cbf11d681
Oct 06 08:31:54 debian containerd[721]: 2023-10-06 08:31:54.308 [INFO][358141] ipam.go 1203: Writing block in order to claim IPs block=192.168.245.192/26 handle="k8s-pod-network.7f1e4e55ae12bd9d257a47ecb7630ea59029f5da8ef89b3937dec19cbf11d681" host="debian"
Oct 06 08:31:54 debian containerd[721]: 2023-10-06 08:31:54.315 [INFO][358141] ipam.go 1216: Successfully claimed IPs: [192.168.245.206/26] block=192.168.245.192/26 handle="k8s-pod-network.7f1e4e55ae12bd9d257a47ecb7630ea59029f5da8ef89b3937dec19cbf11d681" host="debian"
Oct 06 08:31:54 debian containerd[721]: 2023-10-06 08:31:54.315 [INFO][358141] ipam.go 847: Auto-assigned 1 out of 1 IPv4s: [192.168.245.206/26] handle="k8s-pod-network.7f1e4e55ae12bd9d257a47ecb7630ea59029f5da8ef89b3937dec19cbf11d681" host="debian"
Oct 06 08:31:54 debian containerd[721]: 2023-10-06 08:31:54.315 [INFO][358141] ipam_plugin.go 377: Released host-wide IPAM lock.
Oct 06 08:31:54 debian containerd[721]: 2023-10-06 08:31:54.315 [INFO][358141] ipam_plugin.go 286: Calico CNI IPAM assigned addresses IPv4=[192.168.245.206/26] IPv6=[] ContainerID="7f1e4e55ae12bd9d257a47ecb7630ea59029f5da8ef89b3937dec19cbf11d681" HandleID="k8s-pod-network.7f1e4e55ae12bd9d257a47ecb7630ea59029f5da8ef89b3937dec19cbf11d681" Workload="debian-k8s-samplepod2-eth0"
Oct 06 08:31:54 debian containerd[721]: 2023-10-06 08:31:54.317 [INFO][358123] k8s.go 383: Populated endpoint ContainerID="7f1e4e55ae12bd9d257a47ecb7630ea59029f5da8ef89b3937dec19cbf11d681" Namespace="default" Pod="samplepod2" WorkloadEndpoint="debian-k8s-samplepod2-eth0" endpoint=&v3.WorkloadEndpoint{TypeMeta:v1.TypeMeta{Kind:"WorkloadEndpoint", APIVersion:"projectcalico.org/v3"}, ObjectMeta:v1.ObjectMeta{Name:"debian-k8s-samplepod2-eth0", GenerateName:"", Namespace:"default", SelfLink>
Oct 06 08:31:54 debian containerd[721]: 2023-10-06 08:31:54.317 [INFO][358123] k8s.go 384: Calico CNI using IPs: [192.168.245.206/32] ContainerID="7f1e4e55ae12bd9d257a47ecb7630ea59029f5da8ef89b3937dec19cbf11d681" Namespace="default" Pod="samplepod2" WorkloadEndpoint="debian-k8s-samplepod2-eth0"
Oct 06 08:31:54 debian containerd[721]: 2023-10-06 08:31:54.317 [INFO][358123] dataplane_linux.go 68: Setting the host side veth name to cali68b9b56a958 ContainerID="7f1e4e55ae12bd9d257a47ecb7630ea59029f5da8ef89b3937dec19cbf11d681" Namespace="default" Pod="samplepod2" WorkloadEndpoint="debian-k8s-samplepod2-eth0"
Oct 06 08:31:54 debian containerd[721]: 2023-10-06 08:31:54.318 [INFO][358123] dataplane_linux.go 473: Disabling IPv4 forwarding ContainerID="7f1e4e55ae12bd9d257a47ecb7630ea59029f5da8ef89b3937dec19cbf11d681" Namespace="default" Pod="samplepod2" WorkloadEndpoint="debian-k8s-samplepod2-eth0"
Oct 06 08:31:54 debian containerd[721]: 2023-10-06 08:31:54.356 [INFO][358123] k8s.go 411: Added Mac, interface name, and active container ID to endpoint ContainerID="7f1e4e55ae12bd9d257a47ecb7630ea59029f5da8ef89b3937dec19cbf11d681" Namespace="default" Pod="samplepod2" WorkloadEndpoint="debian-k8s-samplepod2-eth0" endpoint=&v3.WorkloadEndpoint{TypeMeta:v1.TypeMeta{Kind:"WorkloadEndpoint", APIVersion:"projectcalico.org/v3"}, ObjectMeta:v1.ObjectMeta{Name:"debian-k8s-samplepod2-eth0", Ge>
Oct 06 08:31:54 debian containerd[721]: 2023-10-06 08:31:54.365 [INFO][358123] k8s.go 489: Wrote updated endpoint to datastore ContainerID="7f1e4e55ae12bd9d257a47ecb7630ea59029f5da8ef89b3937dec19cbf11d681" Namespace="default" Pod="samplepod2" WorkloadEndpoint="debian-k8s-samplepod2-eth0"
Oct 06 08:31:54 debian containerd[721]: time="2023-10-06T08:31:54.388979383+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.event.v1.publisher\"..." runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2 type=io.containerd.event.v1
Oct 06 08:31:54 debian containerd[721]: time="2023-10-06T08:31:54.389077005+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.internal.v1.shutdown\"..." runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2 type=io.containerd.internal.v1
Oct 06 08:31:54 debian containerd[721]: time="2023-10-06T08:31:54.389088977+02:00" level=info msg="loading plugin \"io.containerd.ttrpc.v1.task\"..." runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2 type=io.containerd.ttrpc.v1
Oct 06 08:31:54 debian containerd[721]: time="2023-10-06T08:31:54.389223823+02:00" level=info msg="starting signal loop" namespace=k8s.io path=/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/7f1e4e55ae12bd9d257a47ecb7630ea59029f5da8ef89b3937dec19cbf11d681 pid=358182 runtime=io.containerd.runc.v2
Oct 06 08:31:54 debian systemd[1]: Started cri-containerd-7f1e4e55ae12bd9d257a47ecb7630ea59029f5da8ef89b3937dec19cbf11d681.scope - libcontainer container 7f1e4e55ae12bd9d257a47ecb7630ea59029f5da8ef89b3937dec19cbf11d681.
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of stuff to consider:

1. Pods that host your containers in Kubernetes are internal resources in the node.
2. VLANs are layer2 (broadcast domains)
3. You seem to be trying to solve a cloud-native scenario with VM area solutions. (It is not impossible, but it might be a bit difficult)
4. Remember that Calico is a Layer3-based networking and security solution for cloud-native environments.

---

VLAN-based solution using macvlan plugin:
Your CNI configuration should look something like this:

```
{
    "name": "mynet",
    "cniVersion": "0.3.1",
    "type": "vlan",
    "master": "eth0",
    "mtu": 1500,
    "vlanId": 5, 
    "linkInContainer": true,
    "ipam": {
        "type": "host-local",
        "subnet": "10.1.1.0/24"
    },
    "dns": {
        "nameservers": [ "10.1.1.1", "8.8.8.8" ]
    }
}
```

annotate your deployment with

```
  annotations:
    k8s.v1.cni.cncf.io/networks: mynet
```

Your Pods should be hooked to that VLAN at this point.

**Note:** If you like to assign vlans to your Pods directly, change the `linkInContainer` to `true` and add the proper annotation to your deployments.

---

**Cloud-native way with Calico:**
While the previous solution works, I would suggest using a true cloud-native way to accomplish your task.
Benefits:

- Simpler management
- Better scalability

Install Calico, and configure `IPPools`

> Note: That `natoutgoing` is disabled for this `IPPool`.

```
kubetl create -f -
apiVersion: projectcalico.org/v3
kind: IPPool
metadata:
  name: ippool-1
spec:
  cidr: <CIDR>
  ipipMode: Always
  natOutgoing: false
EOF
```

**Note:** natoutgoing is turned off, that means each Pod will send a request to the outside using its own IP and if the GW is not aware of that IP it will be dropped.

Use [BGP peering](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PefluN8YM9o&ab_channel=ProjectCalico) to establish Layer3 routing with your GW. (Static routing works too)

Consider using the [Calico eBPF dataplane](https://docs.tigera.io/calico/latest/operations/ebpf/use-cases-ebpf/) if you like to preserve the Client IP inside your cluster.

Comment: Thank you very much! The first thing that popped in my sight was "linkInContainer": true which I have set to false. The other solution looks very interesting as well, I need to try that. I'm not sure if I can build the network as I want with solution 2. I basically need to integrate the Pod IP into an already present VLAN and CIDR with DHCP. Its needs to be just another instance in that L2. I will update when tried.

Comment: By the way I'm using Debian 12.1 for Master and Nodes, Am I on the right path with the NetworkAttachmentDefinition? Because your CNI conf is only the JSON and I figured to put the JSON in that YAML like above

Comment: From a security standpoint there might be an issue with `linkInContainer` approach in `macvlan` model, which is all your containers can communicate with the host network card. If you are forced/adamant to use a layer2 approach `ipvlan` might be a bit better.
CNI conf is a JSON blob in the form of a YAML.
https://www.cni.dev/plugins/current/main/ipvlan/#notes